# Want to import all the categories and their products to new magento install from old one

Tags: magento-1.9, product, importexport, category-products, ce-1.9.2.4

I am creating a dev version of my magento store with new theme installation. The theme is configured perfectly but now I want to bring my all the inventory including *Categories -> products*

I have tried by using an extension but it is not working with the magento version 1.9.2.4, and I have also tried to move all the products but it giving me below error:

> error: "Categories not found"

Please suggest a solution. I am using magento version 1.9.2.4.

Comment: Try to use import export from admin

Comment: you can use category export import magnto extension frome here [https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ds-categories-export-import.html](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ds-categories-export-import.html)

Comment: I have tried and its not working fine with magento version 1.9.2.4 as i have contact with the developer of the extension

Comment: @Arjun Can you please tell me hoe to resolve this error while importing "error: Destination folder is not writable or does not exists."

Comment: Give 777 permission to your root folder of magento or if( !is_writable($destinationFolder) ) {
    Mage::Log($destinationFolder);
    //or
    var_dump($destinationFolder);   
    throw new Exception('Destination folder is not writable or does not exists.');
}    in File: lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

Answer (score 1):

To create a development version of your store, you could better make a copy of your live database and then delete the data you don't need. It's much easier than trying to import the data you need. Think about how to handle attributes, attribute, attribute sets, stores, ...

[`n98-magerun`](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)'s database dump already has a predefined table group for this:

```
n98-magerun.phar db:dump --strip="@development"
```

Please note that this also overwrites your config, so you need to set your base URLs again in the database before accessing your store.

And please .. Make a backup before trying this. If it eventually doesn't work for you, then you could always return to your current state.